# retrieve Top 2 & bottom 2 employees salary in each department

Tags: sql-server

Employees salary table with department number

| salary | deptno |
| --- | --- |
| 15000 | sales |
| 16422 | sales |
| 18654 | tech |
| 25789 | sales |
| 12548 | tech |
| 13598 | tech |

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(SALARY,DEPNO)AS
(
  SELECT 15000,'SALES'UNION ALL
  SELECT 16422,'SALES'UNION ALL
  SELECT 18654,'TECH'UNION ALL
  SELECT 25789,'SALES'UNION ALL
  SELECT 12548,'TECH'UNION ALL
  SELECT 13598,'TECH'UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,'KUMAR'UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,'KUMAR'UNION ALL
  SELECT 70,'KUMAR'UNION ALL
  SELECT 500,'KUMAR'UNION ALL
  SELECT 1000,'KUMAR' 
)
SELECT X.SALARY,X.DEPNO,
 CASE
    WHEN X.TOP_COL IN(1,2)THEN 'TWO MAX_SAL'
    WHEN X.BOTTOM_COL IN(1,2)THEN 'TWO MIN SAL'
 END AS FLAG
FROM
(
  SELECT C.SALARY,C.DEPNO,
  RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY C.DEPNO ORDER BY C.SALARY DESC)TOP_COL,
  RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY C.DEPNO ORDER BY C.SALARY ASC)BOTTOM_COL
  FROM CTE AS C
)X WHERE X.TOP_COL IN(1,2)OR X.BOTTOM_COL IN(1,2)
```

Your sample data is represented by CTE. I have enhanced them with additional department "KUMAR" to show two min and two max salaries

Comment: `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` are not the same, also to avoid an extra sort you can do `LEAD(C.SALARY, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY C.DEPNO ORDER BY C.SALARY ASC) TwoAhead` and `WHERE X.TOP_COL IN(1,2) OR X.TwoAhead IS NULL`